# rpy2 printing twice the output

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I upgraded to rpy2.ipython from rmagic but it seems that every statement now prints to the console. Previously, an explicit print had to be called.

Is there an option to get back the former behaviour ?

[image]

Comment: This is looking like a bug report (clear, with a self contained example), and the issue tracker on bitbucket a good place to report this.

Comment: I've replicated on IPython 2.1.0 and rpy2 2.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now in version_2.4.x on bitbucket:

https://bitbucket.org/lgautier/rpy2/commits/e22cdab51c94a504c4ea9808c6fad2772a34ef5e?at=default#Lrpy/ipython/rmagic.pyT216

Basically, I had a conceptual glitch while trying to fix up that logic - R is a Lisp, and withVisible operates on the code it gets in a way that doesn't translate via rpy2's python wrapper (which will operate in pythons function execution semantics, where the innermost is evaluated, return values passed out, etc.).

Comment: The bugfix release rpy2-2.4.1 was just uploaded to Pypi: it contains Dav's (lightning quick) fix and `pip install rpy2 --upgrade` will fix your installation.